# PHP preg_match() pattern for ffmpeg time

Tags: php, regex

I am hoping someone can help me come up with a pattern to get the time value from the following line of text:

```
frame=   73 fps= 41 q=0.0 size=     136kB time=1.67 bitrate= 668.9kbits/s
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to go

```
preg_match($pattern, $line, $matches);
$time = $matches[0];
```

I have been working on it for ages and cannot seem to get the pattern right. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
/time=(\S+)/
```

(your result will be in `$matches[1]`)

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = "/time=(\S+)/";
```

The first match is in $matches[1] not $matches[0].